# Gstreamer udpsrc plugin query

Tags: linux, udp, gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I am developing an IP Streaming based media player. I am using the following pipelines:

Src:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph2 64depay ! h264parse ! imxvpudec ! imxipuvideosink sync=false
```

Sink:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\x86_64\\bin\\hash.h264 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=153.77.205.139 port=5004 sync=true
```

This was the proof of concept. Now, We wanted to have an application which can perform the same operation but with a little tweak when there is no streaming or when no data from the sink, we need to switch to offline base media player, means play a set of videos offline and when there is data on udp port, switch to streaming.

Following are my queries:

1. Is there any way to find out streaming has been completed after video play over IP
2. Is there any way to find out there is no streaming happening.

Please help. I am ready to help you if you need more details

Comment: For udpsrc there is timeout property, which sends a message on bus if there is no data available (you can try setting it to 1 second), for streaming is complted you should get EOS on the bus again. (try this pipeline gst-launch-1.0 -vvvm udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph2 64depay ! h264parse ! imxvpudec ! imxipuvideosink sync=false)

Comment: I am continuously receiving the following messages after I set timeout to 1. 
 Got message #1657 from element "udpsrc0" (element): GstUDPSrcTimeout, timeout=(guint64)3;

Comment: Got it , the timeout property requires argument in nanoseconds.. It worked.. Is there any way to find out the start of stream in udpsrc plugin, just like EOS from timeout property?

Comment: start of stream could be again determined by timeout if you don’t get timeout there is data!

Comment: How it is to use GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER probe for start of stream

Comment: GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER  is another option too on udpsrc.

Comment: Noted..Thanks . You can post timeout option as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For udpsrc there is timeout property, which sends a message on bus if there is no data available (you can try setting it to 1 second), for streaming is complted you should get EOS on the bus again. (try this pipeline `gst-launch-1.0 -vvvm udpsrc port=5004 timeout=100000000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph2 64depay ! h264parse ! imxvpudec ! imxipuvideosink sync=false`)